# Change JetPack Load More HTML MarkUp

Tags: wordpress, infinite-scroll, jetpack

I want to know how to change Jetpack infinite-handle HTML markup.
I found the default markup in **infinity.js** in /wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/infinite-scroll/ like the following code :

```
    Scroller = function( settings ) {
        var self = this;

        // Initialize our variables
        this.id               = settings.id;
        this.body             = $( document.body );
        this.window           = $( window );
        this.element          = $( '#' + settings.id );
        this.wrapperClass     = settings.wrapper_class;
        this.ready            = true;
        this.disabled         = false;
        this.page             = 1;
        this.offset           = settings.offset;
        this.currentday       = settings.currentday;
        this.order            = settings.order;
        this.throttle         = false;
        this.handle           = '<div id="infinite-handle"><span><button>' + text.replace( '\\', '' ) + '</button></span></div>';
        this.click_handle     = settings.click_handle;
        this.google_analytics = settings.google_analytics;
        this.history          = settings.history;
        this.origURL          = window.location.href;
        this.pageCache        = {};

etc...
```

Please see the following code from code above, this is what I want to change.

```
this.handle           = '<div id="infinite-handle"><span><button>' + text.replace( '\\', '' ) + '</button></span></div>';
```

I found in another thread how to change the text is using the following hooks and it works well :

```
function filter_jetpack_infinite_scroll_js_settings( $settings ) {

    $settings['text'] = __( 'Load more...', 'i18n' );

    return $settings;

}
add_filter( 'infinite_scroll_js_settings', 'filter_jetpack_infinite_scroll_js_settings', 100 );
```

The questions is, can I change the **this.handle** value using the same method like I did when change the text ?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , you can change the handle value by following,

First dequeue the script.

```
function wpdocs_dequeue_script() {
   wp_dequeue_script( 'the-neverending-homepage' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wpdocs_dequeue_script', 100 );
```

Then add the script `infinity.js` to theme via wp_enqueue_script function in functions.php and change this.handle to your value.

Comment: Is that work if I use JetPack infiniti scroll module?

Comment: yes it's working here. So it will work for you also.

Comment: So I need to use custom infinity.js and bundled with my theme? And need to update infinity.js manually if ( let say: one of JetPack infinity.js function was changed from WordPress side ) ?

Is there any other method to change via Hooks and still using default infinity.js ?

Comment: yes you need to include common infinity.js. What I did is removed the  infinity.js from plugin and used the  infinity.js from theme , There are no other hooks to change the infinity.js content.